# Error al llamar un archivo JSON local desde fetch

Tags: reactjs

Estoy tratando de llamar a un archivo JSON con un fetch en React pero en la consola del navegador me arroja el siguiente error:

**Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON**

Lo raro es que el archivo json está bien porque ya intenté abrirlo incluso desde el navegador y está todo correcto

```
fetch("../../public/json/beers.json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => console.log(res))
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? La ruta al archivo es la correcta

Comment: Si abristes el json desde el navegador es que tienes una url completa del mismo, por lo tanto intenta ponerla completa en lugar de relativa a ver si te funciona, pues quizás la relativa no es como tu crees que debe ser.

Answer (score 0):

Te marca eso porque estás trayendo `HTML`. Tienes que indicarle al `fetch` que tu tipo es de tipo `json`

```
fetch("../../public/json/beers.json",{
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }
    }
)
.then(...)
```

Comment: no se, creo que eso no impide que lo que está intentando leer en esa ruta relativa seguirá devolviendo HTML (seguramente sea una página de error generada en el servidor por poner mal la ruta del archivo json)

Comment: Lo hice así como dijiste y ahora la consola me dice este error


Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Entonces como menciona @masterguru probablemente tu ruta del archivo está mal.

Answer (score 0):

Eso es porque ReactJS es una tecnología front-end, por lo que **no tiene acceso** al sistema de archivos del equipo local (tanto cliente como servidor).

Cualquier ruta indicada en una consulta XHR se entenderá como una ruta o link de navegación de internet.

Por ejemplo, si la URL actual es `localhost:3000/app`, la ruta del post se cargaría como `localhost:3000/app/../../public/json/beers.json`, lo cual se dio a entender que es una ruta que no existe.

Si la aplicación tiene una vista predeterminada para el control de errores, como lo es el error 404, entonces una ruta no encontrada cargara un archivo HTML (a menos que se destine otro tipo de recurso para retornar), lo cual, para una conversión a objeto desde un texto, de hecho generara una excepción como la descrita en la publicación.

Si estás usando la carpeta `public` estándar para elementos estáticos, la forma apropiada seria con la ruta `/json/beers.json`, de manera que, tomando el ejemplo anterior, se debería cargar de la forma:

```javascript
fetch("/json/beers.json")
```

De manera que la ruta cargada seria `localhost:3000/json/beers.json`, ya que al no proveer un dominio en la ruta, esta usara el dominio por defecto, es decir, el actual.

Los assets dispuestos en la carpeta `public` estándar, tienen la particularidad de que se cargan de manera literal, usando la ruta integra.

Puedes consultar la [documentación](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) al respecto para más detalles.